# difference between N and X relays?

Tags: power, relay, ground, protection, short-circuit

I have seen in some SLDs for overcurrent relays there is a X unit and N unit. I understand that the N unit grounding relay is for zero sequence and the G unit is sensing the current flows through the Neutral grounded part of an equipment (like a delta-Y grounded transformer). what I don't understand is how does a 51X relay senses the ground faults?
Thanks[image: image is from one of the previous client's reports in SKM software]

Comment: @Rezzz2022 - Welcome :-) It seems you were getting frustrated, but you are **required** to comply with the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) on Stack Exchange sites. (The short version of the CoC is "Be Nice" - and if you can't be nice then *don't write anything*.) Your earlier "snarky" comment, and your later one with lots of "SHOUTING" have both been deleted. Please don't take things personally if someone else doesn't understand your question. Your two choices are either to reply politely to them, or don't reply. Any sort of unkind reply is *not allowed*. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I appreciate your concern. I understand these kind of community's guidelines and I have even seen wonderful people in stack communities who really help. for instance there is one in this post as well. but the reason that I got frustrated is I see people from a different background come and drop a comment just to get credit and increase their activity in this way. anyone with this background would get it that the topic and the body were asking the same question. Thanks Sam for caring about the community.

Answer (score 0):

The web tells me that using a 3Ph CM choke acts as an RCD to a 4th relay.

This relay is referred to as a residual ground overcurrent or 51N (or 50/51N) relay.

51X has some do not use caveats.

https://manualzz.com/doc/o/r8c4f/emr-3000-eaton-motor-relay-51x-inv-measured-ground-fault-protection-module

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying that 50/51X relay is same as the 50/51N with some specific conditions?

Comment: that is not what I said, no they are not the same

Comment: perhaps ANSI stds may shed some light on this fuzzy definition http://www.csanyigroup.com/ansi-standards-for-protection-devices

Comment: Even ANSI just talks about N and G and doesn't even talk about X. I have the settings for the X relay but I'm not sure where to put the CT in my model in EASYPOWER. what is making sense to me (based and the CT ratio and Pick up setting of the X relay) is I should put the CT in Y grounded side of the transformer. but I don't know why they 3 ground fault relays. ( one is 50/51G, one is SE330, and last 50/51X) Thanks anyways for the help

Comment: I think the difference is X measures current directly while N is implied neutral current from CM offset as a ground fault leakage thus only applies to certain configs